# Creating more than one dynamic div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to dynamically create divs inside new divs:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'item'
};

obj.html = jQuery('<div/>', { class: 'recommended' });
obj.html += jQuery('<div/>', { class: 'bestbuy' });

jQuery('<div/>', obj).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

So, basically it should create something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div name='item'>
    <div class="I_will_be_inside_obj"></div>
    <div class="I_will_also_be_inside_obj"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this only works with ONE appended div, when I try appending the second, all I get is this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div name='item'>
    [object Object][object Object]
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why, and how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the created dom fragment must be an element. You may do this :

```
jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_be_inside_obj').appendTo('#wrapper');
jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_also_be_inside_obj').appendTo('#wrapper');
```

or

```
var obj = { };
obj.html = jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_be_inside_obj');
obj.html += jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_also_be_inside_obj');
jQuery('#wrapper').html(obj.html);
```

If what you want is to make one div wrapping the 2 divs, use this :

```
var obj = { };
var div = $('<div/>').appendTo('#wrapper');
jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_be_inside_obj').appendTo(div);
jQuery('<div/>').addClass('I_will_also_be_inside_obj').appendTo(div);
```

Comment: I do not want to append the two divs inside wrapper, I want to append them inside a div that I am appending in the wrapper

Comment: That second option doesn't look right. Don't you mean to take .html() at the end of each of the jQuery() lines? Of course, this is going string to DOM back to string back to DOM, and might not perform the best.

Comment: @johnsmith OK, I didn't see what was your goal. It's probably the third version, then.

Comment: Whilst class is a reserved name, you can still quote it to use the `jQuery(html, attributes)` syntax: `jQuery("<div/>", { "class": "myclasshere" });`

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery returns is an array-like object. You can't use `+=` on it like that.

For this particular example, you can use `.after()`, but be aware that if the jQuery you're calling `.after()` on contains multiple elements, it will append a clone of the argument after every element.

```
var underConstruction;

underConstruction = jQuery('<div/>', { class: 'I_will_be_inside_obj' });
underConstruction.after(jQuery('<div/>', { class: 'I_will_also_be_inside_obj' }));

jQuery('<div/>').append(underConstruction).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more the "be aware" sentence?

Comment: This works as written because there are only two new "inner" divs. If you wanted to add a third, you couldn't simply call `underConstruction.after()` because that would add a copy of the third div after both the first and second new div. You'd have to call `underConstruction.last().after()` instead.